# Django queryset update performance and optimization

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I've created a bulk delete function that updates all enabled items' `is_active` flag. I've tried updating 5000 records with the following statement

```
Item.objects.filter(owner=request.user.profile, enabled=True, is_active=True).update(is_active=False)
```

But it is painfully slow and  I'm afraid that this is causing my server to run out of memory.

I've previously had the following and it was still quite slow.

```
items = Item.objects.filter(owner=request.user.profile, enabled=True, is_active=True)
for item in items:
  item.is_active = False
  item.save()
```

The database being used is `SQLite` and I am using `Django 1.7`.

I wish to optimize this operation as much as possible. Any pointers or good query optimization docs would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add an index for `owner` if you haven't already but the real performance gain would be obtained by switching to a better database engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saying that you are deleting but in your code you are updating the rows rather than deleting. Aside from this, the format you are using in the first snippet is the way to go.

To increase performance you can use [index_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#index-together) with *owner*, *enabled* and *is_active* fields (note this adds some load while adding items).

But, as @Selcuk commented, if you aim performance, go use some serious database backend like postgresql.

Btw, take a look at [db optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/optimization/) docs Django offers so you can learn some tricks for future implementations ;).

Comment: It's a soft delete. Instead of actually deleting the records, I set is_active to False. This is because there's another function to bring back old records.

Thanks for the information!

Comment: Well yes, but reading the question was confusing (at least for me) coz you are not deleting records, just updating them (doesn't matter if the field is _is\_active_ or anything else, for performance matters, the operation is an update ^^).

Comment: I got the django debug toolbar and it has helped in optimizing my app. Thanks again for the info.